I can't place items from the right in the container
I get this error: Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1965:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:546:12
Another exception was thrown: Unexpected null value.
I am developing a website for a telegram bot.
I have such a class
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CatalogPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CatalogPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 20), // Indent at the top
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/Vector.png',
            width: 36,
            height: 36,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20), // Indent at the top
          Text(
            'Good morning!',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    CatalogItem(
                      image: 'assets/images/pic-1.jpg',
                      title: 'Чіпси \nяблуневі ',
                      price: '\₴40',
                      weight: 50,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    CatalogItem(
                      image: 'assets/images/pic-2.jpg',
                      title: 'Пастила \nфруктова',
                      price: '\₴50',
                      weight: 50,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    CatalogItem(
                      image: 'assets/images/pic-3.jpg',
                      title: 'Тістечко \nз цукатами',
                      price: '\₴30',
                      weight: 50,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    CatalogItem(
                      image: 'assets/images/pic-4.jpg',
                      title: 'Печиво \nбезлактозне \nвівсяне',
                      price: '\₴30',
                      weight: 120,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    CatalogItem(
                      image: 'assets/images/pic-5.jpg',
                      title: 'Печиво \nшпинат не \n«мармурове»',
                      price: '\₴30',
                      weight: 100,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    CatalogItem(
                      image: 'assets/images/pic-6.jpg',
                      title: 'Печиво \nсендвіч \nз зефіром',
                      price: '\₴30',
                      weight: 50,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    CatalogItem(
                      image: 'assets/images/pic-7.jpg',
                      title: 'Печиво \nшоколадне \n«мармурове»',
                      price: '\₴30', 
                      weight: 100,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here's the consturtor ...
class CatalogItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String price;
  final int weight;

  CatalogItem({
    required this.image,
    required this.title,
    required this.price,
    required this.weight,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 149, // Adjust the size of the images as needed
            height: 192, // Adjust the size of the images as needed
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(image),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    '$weight г',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 10
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Text(
                    price,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 11,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


And when I try to place the elements on the right side, I get the error that I indicated earlier, and even when I want to make the container in which the product is located the same, I also get an error, and nothing is displayed on the screen.


Use GridView.count instead of ListView.

Try Wrapping your Row items in a Container and give it height size of 150 and. width. of double.infinity
For example:
 Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 200,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 20, left: 20),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  CatalogItem(
                    image: 'assets/images/pic-1.jpg',
                    title: 'Чіпси \nяблуневі ',
                    price: '\₴40',
                    weight: 50,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  CatalogItem(
                    image: 'assets/images/pic-2.jpg',
                    title: 'Пастила \nфруктова',
                    price: '\₴50',
                    weight: 50,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

I think wrapping it in a Container and give it. size. will fix your problem
let me know if you face the same issue.
Happy Coding :)

It didn't help, the error is the same

can u set size or width and height to catelogItem?
